# Nginx matching location for block attacking requests

Tags: nginx, location, http-status-code-404, block, http-status-code-403

I am receiving requests of this type on my website:

```
/page/70/?s=Itziar%20itu%C3%B1o&tend=ES
```

Varies the page number and search string. Although the end is always *&tend=ES*.

**How can I block them to return an HTTP 443 status code?**

I try for the final characters, always the same (tend=ES)

```
location /\/?tend=ES$ { deny all; }
```

Also I try with the pattern "*/page/70/?s=*"

```
location ~ /page/(.*)/(.*)/?s=(.*) { deny all; }
```

But nothing... Help pls.

Comment: You cannot match the query string with a `location` directive. Try `if ($arg_tend = "ES") { deny all; }`

Comment: I would return a 444 instead. Which is basically no response, closed connection, under Nginx. This makes it a bit harder for people to figure out they have been made out and allows you to better filter their attempts from the logfiles.